# Connecting to Facebook from a remote website with oAuth2

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript-3, oauth-2.0

Just realised i need to connect to have a button on my website that connects to facebook (if not already logged in) and posts to the users wall.

I've only done this from within an iFrame - do i still need AppId etc etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need an App Id to be able to use login on your website.